# Where did Voldemort turn his Diary into a Horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter

We all know Tom Riddle created his first Horcrux with his Diary when he was 16, when the Trace was still on him. If he had created the the Horcrux outside of Hogwarts, the Ministry would've sensed the Magic, irrelevant of whether or not it was good or bad magic (as evidenced when Dobby used the Levitation Charm and Harry was framed and when Harry used the Patronus Charm in his 5th year). If he had made it elsewhere like Hogwarts, his magic may have remained unTraced.

Comment: The diary, the Chamber of Secrets, and Moaning Myrtle were all connected, so the implication was he did it while he was still at Hogwarts.

Comment: @Radhil so his creation of a Horcrux was unTraced?

Comment: I always assumed that the Horcrux had to be made right away, i.e., within a few minutes or perhaps at most a few hours of the murder.  No?

Answer (score 8):

### Most likely he created the Diary at Hogwarts.

***Timeline***

- Moaning Myrtle died in June 1943
- Tom stays at Hogwarts that summer
- Tom kills his grandparents and frames his uncle
- Year 6 starts
- Tom is seen asking Slughorn about creating 7 Horcruxes
- December 31 1943

Somewhere between these 6 months Tom creates his first, potentially second, Horcrux. Creating it out of school would risk him being detected by the trace, and Ministry officials finding him. Having the whole castle essentially to himself all summer, on the other hand, is the perfect place to set up shop and create some wonders of dark magic.

We also know he was aware of the Room of Requirements and the Chamber of Secrets, both perfect hiding places within the school to create illicit materials.

Comment: he could have already created his first horcrux before talking to Slughorn, and was just trying to get his opinions on what would happen if he made more

Comment: @user13267 yes the meeting with slughorn is more the starting date for potentially the second horcrux but since the date for the meeting isnt know n, nor is which came first(ring or book)it can go either way /shrug,